# Logstash input plugin s3snsqs plugin

Tags: plugins, logstash, opensearch

We have stack currently with **s3 --> SQS --> Filebeat --> Logstash --> Opensearch.**
we have decided to change the way Logstash has been receiving logs, instead of Filebeat I am trying to pull the logs from Logstash input plugin **"s3snssqs"**

Issue : the same has been tested in dev phase and it worked fine.
Now I have tried implementing the same in QA env, the average number of logs received with Filebeat as input in more compare ( in 1000's ) to when receiving logs from plugin ( in 100's ).
Not sure where the logs are missing out

Below is the config I am using with config.

```
  s3snssqs {
    region                     => "us-west-1"
    from_sns                   => false
    consumer_threads           => 2
    s3_default_options         => { "endpoint_discovery" => true }
    queue                      => "n11-us-va-03-alb-logs-message-queue"
    access_key_id              => "#########"
    secret_access_key          => "#############"
    type                       => "sqs-logs"
    tags                       => ["alb-logs"]
    sqs_skip_delete            => false
    codec                      => json
    s3_options_by_bucket       => [
      { bucket_name => "n11-us-va-03-alb-logs-message-queue"
        folders => [
          { key => ".*/alb.*"
            codec => "json_stream"
            type => "ALB"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Can anyone please help me out what setting am i doing wrong
Thank you